# How to perform a fast web request in C#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I have a HTTP based API which I potentially need to call many times. The problem is that I can't get  the request to take less than about 20 seconds, though the same request made through a browser is near instantaneous. The following code illustrates how I have implemented it so far.

```
WebRequest r = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://example.com/http/command?param=blabla");
var response = r.GetResponse();
```

One solution would be to make an asynchronous request but I would like to know why it takes so long and if I can avoid it. I have also tried using the WebClient class but I suspect it uses a WebRequest internally.

**Update:**

Running the following code took about 40 seconds in Release Mode (measured with Stopwatch):

```
WebRequest g = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
var response = g.GetResponse();
```

I'm working at a university where there might be different things in the network configuration affecting the performance, but the direct use of the browser illustrates that it should be near instant.

**Update 2:**

I uploaded the code to a remote machine and it worked fine so the conclusion must be that the .NET code does something extra compared to the browser or it has problems resolving the address through the university network (proxy issues or something?!).

Comment: How did you determine that it is the web request that takes time? I usually do not have any performance issues with the HttpWebRequest class. Have you tried having the application performe several calls, and if so, did all calls take as much time?

Comment: Does it happen with all urls, such as google.com?  What about using a non-ssl url?

Comment: Yeah, Fredrik's comments and suggestions are good. There is no reason that HttpWebRequest should have poor performance in any way (let alone *that* poor) - after all it's using the same protocol as the browser.

Comment: Do you have the same performance problems when getting the response of a webpage like, say "http://www.google.com"?

Comment: Are you running in debug mode?  Requests that take 20-30 seconds in debug tend to be near instantaneous in release mode.

Comment: Regarding your update; I tried the same code, running it twice in a row during immediately after each other (first request to www.google.com, second to www.bing.com); the first one takes ~1 second, the second one less than one millisecond. I would search the solution elsewhere than in that code.

Answer (score 31):

This problem is similar to another post on StackOverflow:
[Stackoverflow-2519655(HttpWebrequest is extremely slow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519655/httpwebrequest-is-extremely-slow/3603413#3603413)

Most of the time the problem is the Proxy server property.  You should set this property to null, otherwise the object will attempt to search for an appropriate proxy server to use before going directly to the source.  Note: this property is turn on by default, so you have to explicitly tell the object not to perform this proxy search.

```
request.Proxy = null;
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
}
```

Comment: upvoting, looks like it's also true for the HttpClient

Answer (score 13):

I was having the 30 second delay on 'first' attempt - JamesR's reference to the other post mentioning setting proxy to null solved it instantly!

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_site.url);
request.Proxy = null; // <-- this is the good stuff

...

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 3):

Does your site have an invalid SSL cert? Try adding this

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AlwaysAccept);

//... somewhere AlwaysAccept is defined as:

using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Net.Security;

public bool AlwaysAccept(object sender, X509Certificate certification, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't close your Request. As soon as you hit the number of allowed connections, you have to wait for the earlier ones to time out. Try

```
using (var response = g.GetResponse())
{
    // do stuff with your response
}
```

Comment: What is the limit for allowed connection? Is it 2?