# Why is my Initial call in RestSharp really slow? but others after are very fast

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, restsharp

I am making calls to a WEB API using RESTSHARP and they work fine. However, the Initial call to the API (regardless of what call it is) can sometimes take up to 10 seconds to get a response. Every other call after that is really quick. Does anyone know a way around this?

I am running a WPF 4.0 application

code:

```
var client = new RestClient(apiAddress);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: That's ususally some firewall or other network issue. Not your code.

Comment: First call from a fresh client, or first call to a fresh server?

Comment: Perhaps DNS problem. Try with IP only.

Comment: The app pool in IIS was not started

Comment: I would suggest it is possibly the service starting, or resuming from a rest state.

Comment: I've just had this problem too. In our case the problem was IIS had put the pool/site to sleep and it took a while (23.8 seconds) to wake up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's most likely the network settings causing this problem. I recently had the same issue and it turned out that when using `HttpWebRequest` or RestSharp it was trying some auto configuration to look for a proxy server.

Open the network settings in Internet Explorer and disable auto configuration for the local network. In my case this resolved the delay for the first request in RestSharp as well.

Comment: This did fix the problem Servy. I have marked this as correct, however it wont be any use to me as I am developing a commercial application which is to be installed on multiple computers and I cant force users to disable this option. Thanks though for clarifying.

Comment: You can also do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519655/httpwebrequest-is-extremely-slow

Answer (score 5):

I had attempted @skrause's answer, but it wasn't work for me.
I spend much time, and finaly I solved it. This my sulotion.

```
public class SimpleWebProxy : IWebProxy
{
    public ICredentials Credentials { get; set; }

    public Uri GetProxy(Uri destination)
    {
        return destination;
    }

    public bool IsBypassed(Uri host)
    {
        // if return true, service will be very slow.
        return false;
    }

    private static SimpleWebProxy defaultProxy = new SimpleWebProxy();
    public static SimpleWebProxy Default
    {
        get
        {
            return defaultProxy;
        }
    }
}

var client = new RestClient();
client.Proxy = SimpleWebProxy.Default;
```

Answer (score 2):

Tried to get rid of the auto configuration to look for a proxy server with this

```
System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

If You use winforms etc. in app.config after connectionstrings:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true">
    <proxy usesystemdefault="True"/>
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Hi, i used this code configuration and it's now work "never work "

Comment: @Osamakhodrog Did it work or not? What signifies with "never work"?

Comment: It worked for me, I think the key statement is "winforms" although in my case it was a console app. It's probably not the same for a web server.

Comment: for a website its the same, however app.config is called web.config