# RestSharp really slow on the initial call or when there is a time gap between calls. But fast on other calls

Tags: c#, .net, rest, console-application, restsharp

I am using RestSharp in a .net console application for making Rest Calls (Got the Nuget package today). The initial call or the calls after some time gap are slow, rest of the calls that I make through the application are fast. Is there a way to fix all the Rest calls to be fast? The slow call takes 1sec100ms but fast calls take less than 10ms. I have looked at the following posts but none of the methods suggested seem to be work.

[Why is my Initial call in RestSharp really slow? but others after are very fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259964/why-is-my-initial-call-in-restsharp-really-slow-but-others-after-are-very-fast)
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/restsharp/o39OBjAgx14/7_KuG5V6xCwJ
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/restsharp/2wNawCIPfwM

The most popular method suggested being changing the  Internet Options --> Connections tab --> LAN settings --> uncheck "Automatically detect settings".
But even that doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Optimize your Data Access layer

Comment: There is no Data Access Layer, I am calling a java REST service. But the problem is with RestSharp. Nothing wrong with the service.