# WebRequest.GetResponse() taking too much time

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I´m writing a function to do a query to a webservice, hosted locally on my computer. It works fine, but the GetResponse method is taking more time than what I expect. More specifically, when I do the request on my browser, it takes about 10 milliseconds and the GetResponse method is taking far from that like 300 milliseconds.

Am I doing something wrong on the code?, something I can improve?

```
    public static string CargarListaRutas()
    {
        WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8080/services/rest/184108301/listaRutas/");
        request.Timeout = 2000;
        WebResponse response;
        string responseFromServer;
        try
        {
            using (response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            responseFromServer = String.Empty;
        }

        return responseFromServer;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not because the browser is using the cached version? You could try CTRL + F5 to force the browser to reload the page and not use cache to test timing.

Comment: If itsme86's comment doesn't help. This might be caused by the automatic proxy detection. Try setting request.Proxy = null. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3603413/442078

Comment: itsme86, you are right. When I clean the cache the request takes about 300 ms just like my application. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that your browser is so much faster because it's using cache. Try CTRL + F5 to force the browser to reload the page and not use cache to test timing.