# GetResponse in using statement C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am trying to get response using below code

```
public void  Stream GetResponse()
{
    WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();
    responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    return responseStream;
}
```

But it returns

> 500 - Internal server

error, so I am trying to `GetResponse` in using

```
public void  Stream GetResponse()
{
    using(WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
    {
         responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    }

    return responseStream;
}
```

Now when I try to access this `responseStream` from calling method it returns this error

> The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

How do I get response in `using` and then return it?

Comment: You can't. The `using` statement explicitly says to dispose the stream after leaving the using block. Anyone trying to use the stream you're returning will be working with a disposed stream. `500 - Internal server error` has nothing to do with your code. The server you're connecting to is throwing an error.

Comment: @Rob Thank you for explanation. But when more data is sent to request, it gets slow. So i was trying to follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519655/httpwebrequest-is-extremely-slow

Comment: Whoever is calling `GetResponse` is responsible for disposing the stream. So you could do something like `using (var s = GetResponse()) { //do work }`

Comment: What does your data look like that you are requesting, and what does the rest of your code look like

Comment: @DonaldJansen I am basically sending data to SOAP. I have updated rest of code

Comment: have you tried to only post a xml body (and remove the SOAP Header), the url that you are sending to is it Asp.net ?

Comment: @Richa could you please confirm from your Server team, that SOAP is enabled on server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791794/client-to-send-soap-request-and-received-response

Comment: @RamSingh Yes it was working fine till yesterday. Seems to be some issue with server i guess.