# First Webrequest is very slow

Tags: c#, networking

My problem is when using WebClient or WebRequest/HttpRequest that the first request often takes a bit more than 40 seconds and all subsequent ones only around 250 milliseconds regardless of size (if it is serveral k characters or only 40). Im only trying to get JSON data from some endpoint.

- with WebClient I use `wc.DownloadString("some address");`
- with WeRequest I use `(HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("some address")` and `webRequest.GetResponse();` with according stream handling afterwards

I already looked around for a Solution, and found:

- `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy();`
- `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;`
- `webclient.Proxy = null;`
- `webclient.Proxy = GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy();`

The above mentionen options are NOT reliable working for me.

Are there any other ways to reliable fix this huge delay for first Request? I would prefere a solution without external libs if possible.

As a note I use .Net Framework 4.5.

Comment: Have you used Wireshark or similar to see what's happening on the network? That's what I'd do next.

Comment: The proxy is probably taking long time to return data.  I agree with Jon Skeet to use a sniffer to find exactly where the long delay is occurring.

Comment: @jdweng, there is no proxy in my network.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I looked into the Wireshark log, the ist no connection to the server prior to the metionen 40 seconds then it is a mix of TCP and TLSv1. What else should I look for?

Comment: HTTP uses TCP as the transport layer.  A secure connection can use TLS so you have to look all three (HTTP, TCP, and TLS).  Responses should be under 1 second so I would start by looking at large gaps of time.

Comment: Do you you have https (s for secure).  Try removing the 's' which you may not need.

Comment: So what *does* happen before the 40 seconds? My guess is that it's trying to talk to something else, which is then failing.

Comment: @jdweng, the https is enforced by the remote (the connection if createt with http ir will switch over to https)

Comment: @JonSkeet, i invetigatet the logs further and also used Microsoft Network monitor and found that the application is trying to connect via ipv6 to the first address returnen when I use nslook on the domain, the the second ipv6 entrie both fail. Then on the first ipv4 it works.
So is ther a way to enforce ipv4? however I have also ipv6 seen working

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384945

Comment: tyvm, i think i can solve it by myself now

Comment: That is if the sever is secure.  If the server is not secure and you use https then it will add additional delays trying to go secure which may be the reason for the long delay.  Without seeing the sniffer results I do not want to come to any conclusions.  again it could be using the wrong try of connection (like IPV4/ IPV6) or using a hot spot which is blocking the connection.  It may be due to a firewall or virus checker.