# How to improve slow DNS with HttpClient?

Tags: c#, dns, httpclient, system.net

I have one request for a specific domain that take a really long time to complete : 22 seconds in average. The request itself does not return a lot of data.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();  //instantiated at app start and reused 
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://www.somedomain.com");
var result = await httpClient.SendAsync(request); //take a really long time
```

After some debugging, it seems related to DNS. If I run the exact same request but replace domain name by IP, it's fast (< 200 ms).

It's also fast if I run the request a second time using same `HttpClient` instance. However, if I run that second request after more than one minute it's slow again (probably because connections are closed automatically after 1 minute).

Is there a way to improve this ? (eg: to make sure resolved DNS entries would stay in cache for a long period). Also why is DNS so slow for that domain when using `HttpClient` ? If I try to access that domain using Chrome it's blazing fast (even after flushing DNS and clearing cache). A DNS lookup of that domain using an online service is also very fast. Reported TTL is 60 minutes.

---

EDIT: I have tried to increase `ServicePointManager.DnsRefreshTimeout` (which is set by default to 2 minutes). But it does not help.

Calling `Dns.GetHostEntry("somedomain.com")` is instantaneous and return the right IP. I don't know why request with `HttpClient` are so slow.

Comment: check this thread https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/18348, it is long. If you are using .NET Core, check SocketsHttpHandler.PooledConnectionLifetime

Comment: See also "Consider using Happy Eyeballs or similar in SocketsHttpHandler" https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/26177

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what is wrong: the domain that is slow has an IPV6 address in the DNS records.
This can be confirmed by calling this function:

```
Dns.GetHostEntry("somedomain.com")
```

First it tries to connect using IPV6. Eventually, a timeout occurs. Then it tries IPV4 (and it works). This explains why it is so slow. The solution I have found so far is to force IPV4 by resolving the domain name myself:

```
var uri = new Uri("somedomain.com");
var builder = new UriBuilder(uri);
var addresses = await Dns.GetHostAddressesAsync(uri.Host);    
builder.Host = addresses
                 .First(x => x.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork) //IPV4 only
                 .ToString(); 
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, builder.Uri);
request.Host = uri.Host;
```

Maybe there is a better way. I can't use `SocketsHttpHandler` since i'm stuck with `.NET Framework 4.5`

Comment: I know this comment is a little old, but there is a .net standard backport: https://www.nuget.org/packages/StandardSocketsHttpHandler/

Answer (score 0):

An other working solution using `SocketsHttpHandler` and `HttpClient` here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70475741/1529139

It uses IPv4 over IPv6 at connection time.

It did the job for me

Answer (score -1):

It's not only about caching DNS query. If you create new client for every request, then before every request both TCP and HTTP handshakes are made -- which makes your single request slow. This is probably the reason why subsequent requests with "old" agent are faster -- handshakes are only made before first request, but not before second one.

Comment: Did you saw the comment in my code ? "HttpClient instance is instantiated at app start and reused between subsequent requests". It does not help in my case because 30 minutes will elapse between those requests and after 1 minute, it's slow again.

Comment: Read code before commenting