# m_defaultpriority==0 error in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I fetching some data in a `unity` game using `WWW` library.
After some time an error starts to show up in unity-editor saying

```
m_DefaultPriority == 0
UnityEngine.WWW:.ctor
```

On unity forum it is said that this happens when there are too many concurrent `WWW` threads. But there are maximum 3 simultaneous `WWW` threads at a time.
Can anyone tell me what is the possible cause of this error and how to resolve it.

Here is my connection making code:

```
IEnumerator Load (ServerRequestData data,float delay=0)
    {
        if(delay>0)
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (delay);

        lastCallType = data.requestType;
        requestsAwaiting++;
        data.timeStamp= System.DateTime.Now.ToString ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff");

        double time= System.DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;

        WWW www;
        if (data.requestFrom != null){
            www = new WWW (data.requestUrl, data.requestFrom);
        }else{
            www = new WWW (data.requestUrl);//Get request
        }

        this.concurrentWWWThreads++;

        yield return www;

        requestsAwaiting--;


        AfterResponse(www,data,time);

        www.Dispose();
        www=null;
        this.concurrentWWWThreads--;

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe if you actually post your WWW code, someone will provide another way of making a connection without WWW.

Comment: @Programmer thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `WWW`, use `UnityWebRequest` instead. The code below translates your `WWW` load function into the new Unity web API. Since your original code is not complete, I wasn't able to test it,so it may may not work. You may have to make a little bit of modification if it doesn't work.

```
IEnumerator Load(ServerRequestData data, float delay = 0)
{
    if (delay > 0)
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

    lastCallType = data.requestType;
    requestsAwaiting++;
    data.timeStamp = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff");

    double time = System.DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;


    UnityWebRequest www;
    if (data.requestFrom != null)
    {
        www = UnityWebRequest.Post(data.requestUrl, data.requestFrom);
    }
    else
    {
        www = UnityWebRequest.Get(data.requestUrl);
    }

    this.concurrentWWWThreads++;

    yield return www.Send();

    if (www.isError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error Occoured: " + www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Successfully Uploaded Form!");
    }

    requestsAwaiting--;


    AfterResponse(www, data, time);

    www.Dispose();
    www = null;
    this.concurrentWWWThreads--;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But the reason for my problem is still unknown. And how do you know the same problem will not reproduce with this solution.

Comment: also my version of unity is 4.6.7 and this UnityEngine.Experimental.Networking was added in later versions. Can you provide any link to the reference of the library you are referring.

Comment: @Jain `UnityWebRequest`  is a new Unity API that replaces `WWW`. You must have Unity 5.3 and above for this to work. http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html I am using 5.4. In Unity 5.4, it is no longer in Experimental mode and can be used by including `using UnityEngine.Networking;`

Comment: Backup your project before updating Unity. What I mean by backup is to close Unity then duplicate your project folder just in-case.

Comment: Need a solution for `Unity 4.6.7` only. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Jain Don't know why you are still using disconnected 4.  Another solution is to use `WebRequest`. You must use multi-Thread to call the `WebRequest`  functions. There many C# examples out there. Just google `WebRequest` examples.  Also look here on how to make it very fast http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119347/how-to-perform-a-fast-web-request-in-c-sharp